# Weird display problem with strokes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, bug

I had this problem recently in Adobe Illustrator where whenever I draw a stroke it shows sometimes parts that doesn't really exist in it, like in this screenshot:

[image: stroke problem screenshot]

but in the outline view:

[image: stroke outline view]

as you can see, there is no explanation for the added/removed parts, also they are all the exact same strokes (copied and rotated), so if it was a problem with the stroke itself it should be the same in all of them, and not a different deformation in each one.

he are the stroke settings:

[image: stroke settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems that the strokes are just *seperate* all you would need to do is Select the Paths → Right Click → *Join*

You can also just use the Projecting Cap <sub>(aspect)</sub> [image]  (highlighted)

Comment: Unfortunately they are actually joined (see the video in this [link](https://goo.gl/Tw5F4g)), I've also tried all possible caps and joins but it's always there, seems like a bug

Comment: @MohamedHaddi perhaps you just need to manually drag in the arm on the corners (the arms are the thinner lines with a dot on the end, that define the shape of the path)

Comment: @MohamedHaddi I can't tell from the video, but there's either an extra arm, or an extra anchor point on the [end of this shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bupN.png)

Comment: oops, I just realized that the arm in the left side of the anchor point was dragged to the opposite side and that's what caused the problem... so I converted the anchor points to corners. that was dump haha, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well it came down to solution of:

1. Cap
2. Corner
3. Align

[image: Illustrator stroke pallet]